# Tensorboard 1.0 Histogram tab

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

What does the Histogram tab (not the Distributions tab) in Tensorboard (TensorFlow 1.0) represent? Can it be intrepreted as a true histogram?

[Histogram Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZv7q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a this [reply](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5381) by Dandelion Mane on a similar question:

"It's a normalized density. I wouldn't describe it as a probability density,
although I think calling it one would be justifiable."